# How to capture back key event from activity opened from browser intent while opening twitter

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j in android app to integrate twitter, i am calling twittershare activity of twitter4j from my app activity, it openes browser for twitter login, when i clicked back key it is going back to PrepareRequestTokenActivity Activity but not in 
onNewIntent(Intent intent) , so how do i capture back key event from browser

Comment: [Are you telling about this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what `PrepareRequestTokenActivity`, `twittershare activity`, etc are, but here is a general note:

When you press back, you are not triggering a new Intent to previous activity; you are merely bringing it up from the stack. Essentially this will call `onResume()` of the background activity. If you want the `onNewIntent()` of previous activity to be called, you should override the `onBackPressed()` of current activity, and start a new `Intent` to the previous activity. Provided ofcourse, that the previous activity is declared as `singleInstance` or `singleTask`.

Comment: my current activity is browser activity openning twitter, how do i override onBackPressed() of browser activity

Comment: You cannot capture browser's back key, because it is not your application or activity. Say you are in ActivityA, and browser is launched from here, you can know that the user has come back from browser to ActivityA when ActivityA's onResume() is called.